# How to use generic type in a map?

Tags: java, generics

Previously, I wrote a method for a specific entity class called `Address` and here's the code :

```
private List<AddLuceneWork> buildAddLuceneWorks(List<Address> addresses) {
    List<AddLuceneWork> addWorks = new LinkedList<>();
    session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
    searchIntegrator = ContextHelper.getSearchintegrator(session);
    entityIndexBinding = searchIntegrator
            .getIndexBindings()
            .get(Address.class);  // specific type
    // ...
    return addWorks;
}
```

And now, I want to make the input to be generic, so that no matter what entity can be processed. But I didn't use generic type before and I don't know how to use it properly :

```
private <T> List<AddLuceneWork> buildAddLuceneWorks(List<T> entities) {
    List<AddLuceneWork> addWorks = new LinkedList<>();
    session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
    searchIntegrator = ContextHelper.getSearchintegrator(session);
    entityIndexBinding = searchIntegrator
            .getIndexBindings()
            .get(Address.class);  // <- how to change it to generic ?
    // ...
    return addWorks;
}
```

I tried the following, but they didn't work :

- `.get(T);`
- `.get(T.class);`
- `.get(clazz.getClass());` where `Class<T> clazz = null;`

Comment: It's a `List`, not a `Map`. And a `List.get(int)` takes the *index* (not the class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to **Type Erasure** your code at `Runtime` is actually

```
private List buildAddLuceneWorks(List entities) {
```

Such that it cannot work, you need to add an additional parameter of type `Class` to provide the expected type explicitly like this:

```
private <T> List<AddLuceneWork> buildAddLuceneWorks(List<T> entities, Class<T> clazz) {
```

Then `get(Address.class)` will then be `get(clazz)`

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I'll keep learning how type erasure works. By the way, is there any method to keep the param generic, without using the second parameter ? Such as `List<Class<?>> entities` ?

Comment: You switch from a list of object T to a List of Class, it sounds to be totally different from your initial intention but if it is fine with your needs why not?

Comment: Ah, I can't. I should load all entities and `List<Class<?>>` just loads all the class types... You're right, they're totally different. I'll use your proposition.

Comment: the best you can do is to get the class of an element at runtime but it can be error prone if you have class of different types like A and B that both extends C, your expected type is C and in your list you have an instance of A and B it will then use as class either A or B depending on the reference element which is not what you want